# Aumentar los valores de los elementos de un array

Tags: javascript

Estoy enviando números (salarios) aun array en Javascript, quiero que el primer trabajador gane el valor que se introduzca de primeras, el segundo 15% mas que el primero el tercero 15% mas que el segundo y así.

Tengo un array salaries y ahí envió todos los salarios,
después recorro el array y le saco el 15% a cada uno de los salarios
después le sumo a cada uno de los salarios desde la posición `i + 1` el 15% para dejar el primero intacto y envió al array *finalSalaries*.

El problema es que obtengo como resultado en la posición 2 **`NaN`** y creo que es lógico que me sobraría un *%* ya que corrí una posición del array.

¿Cómo podría arreglar esto para que me muestre todos los valores de los salarios incluyendo el primero que no aumentó?

Este es mi código:

```js
 const n = 3;
    
    const salaries = [];
    const finalSalaries = [];
    
    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        const salary = Number(prompt("ingrese el valor del salario del trabajador"));
        salaries.push(salary);
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<salaries.length; i++){
        const x = salaries[i]*15/100;
        const c = salaries[i+1]+x;
        finalSalaries.push(c);
    }
    
    console.log(finalSalaries);
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: `for ( i=0; n > i; i++ ) salario[i] = salarioInicial * ( 1 + 0.15 * i )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cómo podría arreglar esto para que me muestre todos los valores de los salarios incluyendo el primero que no aumentó?

Pues tu mismo te lo estás diciendo: no empieces por el primero, sino por el segundo:

```js
    const n = 3;

    const salaries = [ 100, 200, 300 ];
    const finalSalaries = [];

    finalSalaries.push( salaries[0] );

    for( i = 1; i < salaries.length; ++i ) {
        const x = salaries[i - 1] * 15 / 100;
        const c = salaries[i] + x;
        finalSalaries.push( c );
    }
    
    console.log( finalSalaries );
```

Answer (score 4):

Efectivamente el problema se encuentra `const c = salaries[i+1]+x;` ya que estás recorriendo cada elemento de salaries y cuando el ciclo llegue al último elemento el índice apuntado será `salaries[3]` que no está asignado aún.

**Ahora la solución**

En lugar de usar un ciclo *for* para llenar *finalSalaries* puedes hacer todo en una línea con `Array.map`:

```js
const n = 3;

const salaries = [ 100, 200, 300 ];
const finalSalaries = salaries.map((salary, index) => 
  index === 0 ? salary : 
                salary + salaries[index - 1] * .15)

console.log( finalSalaries );
```

**¿Cómo funciona?**

**`salaries.map`** toma cada elemento del arreglo y lo usa en una función para devolver un nuevo valor en la misma posición de un nuevo arreglo.

El cuerpo de la función `index === 0 ? salary : salary + salaries[index - 1] * .15` devuelve el mismo valor de salaries cuando se trata del primer elemento y para los demás elementos toma el valor actual de salaries y le suma el 15% del valor anterior de salaries (`salaries[index - 1] * .15`).

Para más información puedes consultar la documentación de `Array.map` en la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.